# How to get div in an arc shape?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to create a div which will contain a quote. This `div` needs to be in arc shape which is 25% of a circle.

**How do I create a div that is in circle shape but use only top left 25% of it's space?**

I have tried borderRadius property which gives a full circle.

```
 <div
        style={{
          border: "1px solid black",
          height: "100px",
          width: "100px",
          borderRadius: "50%"
        }}
      >
        This is where the quotes will be printed
      </div>
```

How to get this div as an arc shape? for example 7th shape in this image

[image: Image demo]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please take a look on this solution:

```css
.quarter-circle {
    position: relative;
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background: none;
     border-left: 1px solid black;
     border-top: 1px solid black;
     border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
     -webkit-border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="quarter-circle">
  <div class="text">
    This is where the quotes will be printed
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course you can move your text any other way, so it would be suitable to your design.

[Snippet external](http://jsfiddle.net/xj8ku71o/2/)

Answer (score 1):

This will create the arc you want. But the div is not a circle. Not 100% sure if this is what you need. This will overlap your text. You can create styles for the text and move it around.

```
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the arc. Now you can transform this to any angle you need.

```css
.arc{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 3px;
    border-color: red transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="arc"></div>
```